# Android calculate percentage of scrolling recyclerView

Tags: android

i'm trying to show percentage of scrolling automatically to end of recylerview item by this code:

```
visibleItemCount = bookContentLayoutManager.getChildCount();
totalItemCount   = bookContentLayoutManager.getItemCount();
firstVisibleItem = bookContentLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

float percentage = (visibleItemCount * 100 / totalItemCount);
Log.e("percent ", percentage + "");
```

but it doesn't correct and i'm trying to find whats is solution of that, it means show percentage of current scrolled recyclerview items

Comment: try getAdapterPosition(); ?

Comment: do you mean % of ongoing count which is already scrolled with total number of items which we have ?

Comment: check out my answer, it would be useful if you could provide usecase

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Recyclerview provides the following methods for vertical and horizontal scroll use the below code,

```
        int offset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
        int extent = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
        int range = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();

        float percentage = (100.0f * offset / (float)(range - extent));
```

Comment: You can always round final value by call `Math.round(percentage);`

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work fine with a recyclerview that has multiple view types... do you know a solution for that case?

Answer (score 0):

I think This will work . try this out and let me know :

```
 int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    float percentage=(lastVisibleItemPosition/totalItemCount)*100;
```